# How to create xpath in appium using Uiautomate viewer?

Tags: android, selenium, mobile, automated-tests, appium

How to create xpath in appium using Uiautomate viewer.Find the attched screenshot here I have content description only.By using this how can i Identify Sign UP button?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Locating by `content-desc`  property in UIAutomator is similar to locating by `name` property in selenium / Appium,

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Sign Up"));
```

Comment: No hope.It is not working. `driver.findElement(By.name("Sign Up")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

xpath using uiautomate viewer is almost same as created on browser. 
For example, in the attached screenshot, the highlighted one has xpath:
//android.view.View[@content-desc=' Sign up']

Generic Format: //[class][other parameters]

Comment: It is not working.                                        `driver.get("https://mobile.twitter.com/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='Sign up']")).click();`

Comment: whats error you are getting ? also before you find element, can you see the which context you are on like driver.getcontext(); it should be Native_App.

Comment: I am using web application in android chrome browser.When I execute the code,eclipse throwing error as "_no such element found_"

Comment: whats the output of driver.getcontext() ??